# Randomize Image Lists

Tags: python, list, image, tkinter, random

I'm trying to randomize a lists of gif images in tkinter. I've manged to get an image on the title page but, for the 2nd frame but I am struggling. For the 2nd frame I want it to randomize images on to the frame, and when I hit contiune it clears the image and places a new image.

I have tried using the glob class, and I have tried a function that randomizes the code, they all resulted in an error or a blank screen. I can't use PIL.

```
import random as rand
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *

window = tk.Tk()

a4 = PhotoImage(file="a.gif")
b4 = PhotoImage(file="b.gif")
c4 = PhotoImage(file="c.gif")
d4 = PhotoImage(file="d.gif")
e4 = PhotoImage(file="e.gif")
f4 = PhotoImage(file="f.gif")
g4 = PhotoImage(file="g.gif")

notes4 = [a4, b4, c4, d4, e4, f4, g4]


def buttonraise():
    frame_test.tkraise(frame_beginning)
    frame_test.config(bg="#F1DDCF")


def listimage():
    for i in range(len(notes4) - 1, 0, -1):
        j = rand.randint(0, i + 1)
        notes4[i], notes4[j] = notes4[j], notes4[i]
        notes4.pop(i)
    bgt = PhotoImage(file="title.png")
    labelbgt = Label(frame_test, image=bg)
    labelbgt.pack(padx=85, pady=10)


def clear():
    for w in frame_test.winfo_children():
        w.destroy()
    listimage()


window.geometry("400x400")
window.config(bg="#F1DDCF")

frame_beginning = tk.Frame(window)
frame_beginning.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

frame_test = tk.Frame(window)
frame_test.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="news")

frame_beginning.tkraise(frame_test)

frame_beginning.config(bg="#F1DDCF")
bg = PhotoImage(file="title.png")
labelbg = Label(frame_beginning, image=bg)
labelbg.pack(padx=85, pady=10)

labelintro = Label(frame_beginning, font=("Castellar", 18), text="Music Theory", bg="#F1DDCF")
labelintro.pack(pady=5)

buttonlog = Button(frame_beginning, text="Continue", width=15, bg="white", command=buttonraise)
buttonlog.pack(pady=50)

buttoncont = Button(frame_test, text="Continue", width=15, bg="white", command=clear)
buttoncont.pack(pady=5)

labelcat = Label(frame_test, text="cat", bg="#F1DDCF")
labelcat.pack(padx=5)

labelbgt = Label(frame_test, image=bg)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Hello, have you considered random.choice() to get a random item from your list of gifs?

Comment: I don't find bgt. bgt = PhotoImage(file="title.png")

Comment: Comment out this `#notes4.pop(i)`

Answer (score 0):

How many image(s) do you want to display?

I have 2 options

Option1:

This will only give `3 images`.

Comment out line 50 and 51.

You cannot use `gif`.

```
a4 = PhotoImage(file="p1.png")
b4 = PhotoImage(file="p2.png")
c4 = PhotoImage(file="p3.png")
d4 = PhotoImage(file="p4.png")
e4 = PhotoImage(file="p6.png")
f4 = PhotoImage(file="p7.png")
g4 = PhotoImage(file="p8.png")


def listimage():
    for i in range(len(notes4) - 1, 0, -1):
        print(i)
        j = rand.randint(0, i + 1)
        (notes4[i], notes4[j-1]) = notes4[j-1], notes4[i] # chnage -1
        #notes4.pop(i)
        #bgt = PhotoImage(file="p2.png")
    labelbgt = Label(frame_test, image=notes4[i])
    labelbgt.pack(padx=85, pady=10)


Put `listimage()` inside looping in `clear()` function.

    def clear():
        for w in frame_test.winfo_children():
            w.destroy()
            listimage()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Option2: For **6 images**.

```
def listimage():
    for i in range(len(notes4) - 1, 0, -1):
        print(i)
        j = rand.randint(0, i + 1)
        (notes4[i-1], notes4[j-1]) = notes4[j-1], notes4[i] # chnage -1
        #notes4.pop(i)
        #bgt = PhotoImage(file="p2.png")
        labelbgt = Label(frame_test, image=notes4[i])
        labelbgt.pack(padx=85, pady=10)
```

Screenshot:

[image]